# remove kth node from end of linked list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to remove the `kth` element from the **END** of a linked list. Here is my code

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


def removeKthNodeFromEnd(head, k):
    if k == 0 or head is None:
        return

    temp = head
    while temp is not None and k > 1:
        temp = temp.next
        k -= 1

    if temp is None or k > 1:
        return head

    trailing = None
    leading = head
    while temp.next is not None:
        trailing = leading
        leading = leading.next
        temp = temp.next

    if trailing is None:
        head = head.next
    else:
        trailing.next = leading.next


head = LinkedList(0)
head.next = LinkedList(1)
head.next.next = LinkedList(2)
head.next.next.next = LinkedList(3)
head.next.next.next.next = LinkedList(4)
head.next.next.next.next.next = LinkedList(5)
head.next.next.next.next.next.next = LinkedList(6)
head.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = LinkedList(7)
head.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = LinkedList(8)
head.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next = LinkedList(9)


removeKthNodeFromEnd(head, 10)

while head is not None:
    print(head.value)
    head = head.next
```

But this does not work and prints out all the values in the linked list from 0 to 9. Why is this the case? If the node to delete is the head node which I check by checking `trailing is None`, then I update `head = head.next`. I am changing `head` to be the next node. I can return `head` after this update and the result of `head = removeKthNodeFromEnd(head, k)` will give me the desired output but why can't I do it the other way without returning anything? For instance in my solution I can get rid of any element in between the first and last node including the last and works just fine. The original head gets updated and node gets removed. But when trying to update the head node `head = head.next` it does not work.

One way I achieved this is by doing the following...

```
if trailing is None:
  head.value = head.next.value
  head.next = head.next.next
```

But why must I use the values? To me this seems the same as

```
if trailing is None:
  head = head.next
  head.next = head.next.next
```

but does not work

Comment: Look at your last code sample. It actually does `(head.next).next = head.next.next`, which is no-op, so no changes in original tree happen. You can do `head.next = head.next.next` to remove item right after `head` (`A -> B -> C` transforms to `A -> C` after this assignment, assuming `head` points to node `A`).

Comment: What about `head = head.next` shouldn't that work? Or even `temp = head.next`, `head.next = None`, `head = temp`. Maybe I'm not understanding you but this should remove it no?

Comment: Assignment to `head` won't work until you return `head` and then use new value. You can modify *attribute* of `head`, but assignment does not modify input parameter. Say, given function `def f(x): x = x + 1`, we can run `x = 2; f(x); print(x)` (prints `2`) or `x = 2; x = f(x); print(x)` (prints `3`).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `head` in that function is a *local* name. Assigning to a local variable never does anything to other variables, even not when they happen to have the same name (like the *global* `head`).

The "trick" you have by moving a linked list value with `head.value = head.next.value` will not work when the list only has one node.

One way to do this, is to *return* the (potentially modified) value of `head`, and expect the caller to assign this back to their own `head` variable.

So:

- in `removeKthNodeFromEnd` make sure all `return` statements are like `return head`, and that you add a `return head` at the very end. In short, `removeKthNodeFromEnd` should always return `head`.
- in the main program, change the call to `head = removeKthNodeFromEnd(head, 10)`

That will solve your issue.

Here are some ideas to make your code more elegant:

- Create a separate class for maintaining the head of the linked list
- Improve the constructor, so that it is easier to initialise a linked list
- Add an iterator so it is easier to print a linked list

```
class Node:  # renamed
    def __init__(self, value, nxt=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = nxt  # is now an argument


class LinkedList:  # added
    def __init__(self, *values):
        self.head = None
        if values:  # populate the list with values
            for value in reversed(values):
                self.push_front(value)

    def push_front(self, value):
        self.head = Node(value, self.head)

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node.value
            node = node.next
    
    def removeKthNodeFromEnd(self, k):
        if k <= 0:
            return
        temp = self.head
        for _ in range(k):
            if not temp:  # k is out of range
                return
            temp = temp.next

        if temp:
            trailing = self.head
            while temp.next:
                trailing = trailing.next
                temp = temp.next
            trailing.next = trailing.next.next
        else:
            self.head = self.head.next
    

lst = LinkedList(*range(10))
print(*lst)
lst.removeKthNodeFromEnd(0)
print(*lst)
```

And if you maintain a `size` attribute, you can do:

```
class LinkedList:  # added
    def __init__(self, *values):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0
        if values:
            for value in reversed(values):
                self.push_front(value)

    def push_front(self, value):
        self.head = Node(value, self.head)
        self.size += 1

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node.value
            node = node.next

    def removeAt(self, k):
        if 1 < k <= self.size:
            trailing = self.head
            for _ in range(k - 2):
                trailing = trailing.next
            trailing.next = trailing.next.next
        elif 1 == k <= self.size:
            self.head = self.head.next
    
    def removeKthNodeFromEnd(self, k):
        self.removeAt(self.size + 1 - k)
```